# getting undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Learning React by coding, here i got this error (Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) ), dont know where is the problem, any suggestion ?

simply useEffect activates setFilteredData which gives :
`

```
{
links: [
  {
    color: 'red'
  },
],
nodes: [
  {
    focused: focused
  },
],
};

`
```

i want to take that data and change it a little, like my logic is, color should be grey or red if id's matches and also focus should be focus if id's matches, english is not my mother language so could be mistakes. any ideas ?
i hope my question is clear, if needs to add something or not clear, just tell me.

```js
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState();
  const LINK_COLOR = "grey";
const LINK_FOCUS_COLOR = "red";

 useEffect(() => {
      const filterData = () => {
     
          setFilteredData({ links: links, nodes: allNodes });
       
      };
     filterData() ;
  
  }, [...]);
  
  
  
    const focusLinkId = currentLink ? currentLink.id : "";
  const focusNodeId = currentNode ? currentNode.id : "";

  const graphData = {
    ...filteredData,
    links: [
      ...filteredData?.links,
      {
        color: filteredData?.links?.map((l) => {
          const color = l?.id === focusLinkId ? LINK_FOCUS_COLOR : LINK_COLOR;
          return color;
        }),
      },
    ],
    nodes: [
      ...filteredData?.nodes,
      {
        focused: filteredData?.nodes?.map((n) => {
          const focused = n?.id === focusNodeId;
          return focused;
        }),
      },
    ],
  };
  
    console.log("graphData:", graphData);


   <Graph
      id="graph-id"
  
      data={graphData ? graphData : visualGraph.model}
     
    />
```

Comment: You have probably got a clickable line number where the code is thrown. But I guess that `...filteredData` throws this as `filteredData` is `undefined`.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski how can i make it so IF it is undefined then dont panic and dont give error ? just wait until its not undefined, i am using 'Optional chaining (?.)'

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, `filteredData` is `undefined` until the response comes back

This should help:

```
const graphData = filteredData && { /* ... */ }
```